# Image from WebView

Tags: android

i m getting a photo from the web,but i see it very large..how could i see it with zoom out?this is my code for webView:

```
public class gavros extends Activity {
    WebView browser;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.efimerides);


            browser =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

            browser.loadUrl("http://...");
        }}
```

Comment: i can see it smaller,manually,with the "2 fingers".That i m asking for is how to see it without zoom out manually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout WebView's setInitialScale method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale(int)